# Question regarding best choice for specifying schema in spark and How to Delete/remove column from rdd spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have two datasets NYC taxi data and weather data. Weather data a huge number of columns from, around 100, of which I need only 5-10. And I want them to be typed instead of strings hence need a schema. I know two ways for this

1. Rdd->Rows-> give schema and then convert to DF
2. Dataframe InferSchema (the documentation says its double passes)

Is inferSchema a good choice for the 100 column thing and don't have to write a StructType or CaseClass for 100 columns? 
And the taxi data with billion+ records which also has around 60 columns but I need only around 10. What would be a suitable choice for this dataset? Write schema for all 60 columns?

Second Question: as I mentioned I don't need all the columns so I'm dropping columns. from the documentation and Internet, I got to know how to do this using DF just with the select function. 
But I in case I have to write schema which in my knowledge is only possible using RDD. How to remove/drop columns in RDD?

Ideally, using any RDD/DF id like to drop columns first then specify a schema. Is this possible?
I know it's a lot of questions but I'm a newbie with spark all this popped up in my mind and i want to do it the right way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RDD to achieve it, it's really simple. Just load your data to DF then select and cast wanted columns.

```
scala> val df = Seq("1","2","3").toDF("c1")
scala> df.show()
+---+
| c1|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)

scala> val newDF = df.select('c1.cast("int"))
scala> newDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
```